# Lower bound of weighted average of sequence

Tags: discrete-signals, power-spectral-density, finite-impulse-response, statistics, averaging

Can anyone prove that
$$\mathrm{avg}\left(\frac {a_i}{\left(1+a_i\right)^2}\right) \ge \frac{\mathrm  {avg}({a_i})}{\left(1+\mathrm{avg}{(a_i)}\right)^2}$$
for a sequence of positive valued elements $a_i, \quad\text{with}\quad i= 1,2,\ldots,N$?

Comment: Unless I went wrong, the inequality does not seem valid everywhere. Don't you have more constraint on the $a_i$?

Answer (score 0):

You can recognize the function $$f: x\mapsto \frac{x}{(1+x)^2}\,.$$

The question can be rephrased as: how do compare the average of the function values $\overline{f(a_i)}$ with the function of the average value $f(\overline{a_i})$? Graphically, this can be illustrated by the following graph (spoiler: from [Behold! Jensen's inequality](http://mark.reid.name/blog/behold-jensens-inequality.html)). Here, the average is represented by $\mathbb{E}$, the statistical expectation, akin to the classical average.

[image: Jensen inequality on a parabola]

The intuition here is the following: for a convex function, as the above, the average of the $y=f(x)$ ($\mathbb{E}[f(x)]$) is higher than the function of the averages of $x$  (or $f(\mathbb{E}[x])$).

In the discrete form, [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) can be proven by induction [Proof 1 (finite form)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Proof_1_(finite_form)).
This inequality is reversed for a concave function. The reverse inequality is the one you are interested in. Now, function $f(x)$ is not concave on $[0,\infty[$, graph from [RechnerOnline](https://rechneronline.de/function-graphs/):

[image: function rechner online]

With $a_1=0$ and $a_1=1$, we get $$\overline{f(a_i)}-f(\overline{a_i}) = 1/8 - 2/9 \le 0 \,.$$

With $a_1=1$ and $a_1=9$, we get $$\overline{f(a_i)}-f(\overline{a_i}) = 17/100 - 5/36 \ge 0 \,.$$

Hence, the inequality has a sign change. It would be valide for instance on some interval $[\alpha,+\infty)$, such that $f$ is concave.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. You are right. The assumption is ai >> 1 to make this lower bound valid.

Comment: Then Proof 1 for finite form would work, for $x> \alpha > 1$, where the function is concave